# loop on data returned after deserializing

Tags: c#, json, instagram, javascriptserializer

I get data from instagram api. So i use below

```
var responseStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encode))
 {
     var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
     var jsonObject = serializer.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());
 }
```

I dont know how to loop on this data. I tried

```
 foreach (var item in  jsonObject)
 {

 }
```

But it gives compile time error  `Type object is not enumerable`

How do i loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable jsonObject is an object which is not an enumerable.
You must specify an enumerable type when deserializing :

```
var jsonObject = serialize.Deserialize<enumerableType>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: I tried and it says cannot resolve symbol enumertableType

Comment: enumerableType is the type of the object you are deserializing and this type must be enumerable if you want to be able to loop on it

Comment: I read data using streamreader. Then deserializing it. How to define this? Please help with more code

Comment: Ok, post an example of the json string you are deserializing

Comment: do you have instagram developer account? if yes then try this link
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/kirannandedkar/media/recent?access_token=1942800834.674061d.8e277cc039334835bd5104083bb4ce4f&max_tag_id=1370433362010